# testing navigation from one view model to other viewmodel

Tags: xamarin, testing, mvvmcross

I am trying to create test which be able to check navigation between two viewmodels.

Some code from ResultViewModel

```
    private IMvxCommand homeCommand;
    public IMvxCommand HomeCommand => homeCommand ?? (homeCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(ShowHomePage));
    private async Task ShowHomePage()
    {
        await _navigationService.Navigate<HomeViewModel>();
    }
```

Testing code
private Mock mvxNavigationService = new Mock();
private Mock resultService = new Mock();

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var viewModel = new ResultViewModel(mvxNavigationService.Object, resultService.Object);

        viewModel.HomeCommand.Execute();

        mvxNavigationService.Verify(service => service.Navigate<HomeViewModel>());

        Assert.Pass();
    }
```

I am getting error
"An expression tree cannot contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments."
on line
mvxNavigationService.Verify(service => service.Navigate());
Not sure where the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

In Xamarin, a dedicated page navigation method is officially provided.

You can navigate between pages like:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync (new Page());
```

You can pop pages from the navigation stack like:

```
await Navigation.PopAsync ();
```

For more usage, please refer to: [Hierarchical Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical).

Comment: my problem is not navigation to page, but creating test which check if navigation is working